# Internal Server Error - ProxyPass & ProxyReseverse (Apache2)

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, apache2

I'm trying to set a ProxyPass & ProxyReverse up so that I can share a domain between 2 different servers.

Looking to achieve:

Domain: https://example.com

Server A: https://example.com/quotes

Server B: https://testing.com/quotes

When I'm setting up the proxy in the `VirtualHost`, it's giving a 500 internal server error.

Sites enabled example:

```
 <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
        SSLCertificateFile ../../certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile ../../certificate.key
        SSLCACertificateFile ../../certificate.ca-bundle

        ProxyRequests Off

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>

        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        <Proxy *>
          Require all granted
        </Proxy>

        ProxyPass /quotes https://testing.com/quotes
        ProxyPassReverse /quotes https://testing.com/quotes
    
        ErrorLog syslog
        LogLevel emerg
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Read the error log of your server.

Comment: Setting `LogLevel` to a higher level like `error` or `warn` could be helpful. `emerg` only logs the most severe problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the vh error logs it will tell you that it does not recognize the url scheme. That is because you have not specified the SSL engine for proxy connections.

You need this whenever you proxy to https:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass /quotes https://testing.com/quotes
ProxyPassReverse /quotes https://testing.com/quotes
```

As an added note YOU DO NOT NEED:

> ```
>     <Proxy *>
>       Require all granted
>     </Proxy>
> ```

Think of these as more related to forward proxying than reverse proxying.